# How to fix LookupError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, error-handling

I want to get a symbol from Unicode database.

After running this thing *(my terminal doesn't support Unicode characters, that's why I do it)*:

```
chcp 65001
```

And this code:

```
print u"\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}"
```

I get an error:

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001
```

**1) What is the problem?**

2) Is there a way not to type `chcp 65001` every time?

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoRun Entry in the registry. Set AutoRun for the command chcp 65001.